# Linux Buffer Overflow Environment Variables

Tags: c, linux, security

I have been reviewing different styles of buffer overflows and ran into a problem I cannot remember why it occurs. The code as follows is the program I am attempt to perform a buffer overflow on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *buff){  
    char buffer[5];
    strcpy(buffer, buff);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    func(argv[1]);
    printf("I'm done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The core concept of the program is very simple, I just overflow the buffer to overwrite the return address of `func()`. That all works great when I give it an address such as `0x0804850c` which happens to be the `<_fini>` of the program. The end result when I implement the overflow with that address is the program quits "gracefully" without printing `I'm done!`. The problem I am running into now is when I attempt to redirect the return address to something say an environment variable located at `0xbfffd89`.

The shell code located in that particular environment variable should simply quit the program after saying `hello`. However that does not occur, the program simply seg faults and that's it. The shell code has already been confirmed to work in the previous program I wrote to test out shell code. Anyone have any ideas why this is not working. Thx

Comment: Run it under gdb to see what triggers the segfault. My guess: the environment variable lives in an area of memory that is readable but not executable. @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: I assume that "shell code" here is jargon for machine code that runs a shell and some external commands, which is what exploits usually want to do. Although in this case it sounds like no actual shell is run.

Comment: @Celada Any suggestions on how I can use GDB to check if the environment variables are READ-ONLY. Also you are correct about the shell code.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Shell code generally defined is the byte code of a binary. In this case I generated the shell code by writing what I wanted out in x86 ASM. When I redirect the return address of the function I direct it to an area of memory that contains a new set of instructions.

Comment: @Blackninja543 I couldn't find a way to check this from inside `gdb` (the closest thing is `info proc mappings` but it doesn't show the permissions). I had to check in `/proc` directly which is not portable, but, oh well. I elaborated the rest in an answer.

Comment: For clarity, the term "shellcode" in a security context refers to the binary payload used to bootstrap access to the compromised system (often by execing a shell process, thus the name).   It does not refer to script code written for the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are located in a region of memory that has read & write permission but not execute permission. I reproduced this easily as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
void (*function)(void);

        function = (void (*)(void))getenv("PATH");
        function();
        return 0;
}
```

Running under `gdb`, I got this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffeb51 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

I then looked up the address 0x00007fffffffeb51 if `/proc/PID/maps` and found a line like this:

```
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

There's a `-` where the `x` (execute) bit would normally be found.

Comment: OK so lets assume I can't change the permissions of the environment variables what other possibilities are there for execution of my shell code outside of the environment variables.

Comment: Plausible scenario for a vulnerable program: an environment variable is copied to the heap. Perhaps the environment variable names a directory and it is concatenated with a filename to form a full pathname in `malloc()`ed memory. Now your buffer overflow can jump to this address on the heap. It will be executable. But you have to guess what this heap address is... good luck with that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Modern linux distros are hardened against this sort of attack.  The NX bit is set for stack pages on x86-64, for example.  And mapping addresses are randomized to prevent the ability to guess from outside the process.  See the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Basically, if you want to write an exploit for a modern system you're going to have to do some more work.

Comment: Correct. What's not obvious about this particular case is that environment variables are, in fact, in the same memory-mapped region as the stack. I didn't know that until now!

Comment: @Celada: actually all of `argc`, `argv`, `envp` and `auxv` and the respective pointers to them are passed to each process on the stack.

Comment: @ninjalj I knew that `argv`, `envp`, and `auxv` were all together in a memory region known as the "user area" but I didn't know it was the same area as the stack. But I was on Solaris back when I learned this some alarming number of years ago, and things might have changed. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Those guys have all been on the stack since v6 unix at least.  Pre-MMU there really wasn't much choice.  It was either there or at the bottom of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the address of the variable between runs? If your system uses something like ASLR, it can be different every run. The address of the argv[1] may be, however, given via some register, so if you supply the return address with the address of instruction doing indirect call via this register (you will probably find such instruction using `objdump -d` on your program), it will run your code at whatever address it will be - assuming this address is in the executable page. And registers are used in your ABI to pass parameters. There can be another problems however...

If you provide more details (possibly, insluding disassembly of the program), maybe it could be answered more specifically.

Comment: I'll add the disassembled code when I get a chance. As far as address space randomization, I have that turned off in my test environment. As Celada showed and I checked on my own environment, my environment variables not non-executable. Do you have any thoughts on how I can insert my code shell code to make it executable. The only way I can think of at this point is by using the environment variables.