# Linux Buffer Overflow Return-to-libc

Tags: c, linux, security

This question is a follow up with a previous question [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946750/linux-buffer-overflow-environment-variables)

The previous question was solved by changing the permissions of the executable with `execstack`. My new problem revolves around another implementation to bypass stack execution protection. This uses [return-to-libc](http://www.infosecwriters.com/text_resources/pdf/return-to-libc.pdf) and involves executing `/bin/sh` against the address of `system()`.

I am currently using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *buff){  
    char buffer[5];
    strcpy(buffer, buff);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    func(argv[1]);
    printf("I'm done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My problem occures when I need to overflow the return address of `func()` to the address `0x00167100`. When I perform the buffer overflow the argument I use is `$(echo -e "\x00\x71\x16\x00")`. The problem however is the least significant `\x00` just before `\x71` gets removed from my argument. In fact I can use `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x71\x16\x00` and the argument passed in will still be `\x71\x16\x00`. The end result is the overriden address before some like `0x08001671` when it should really be `0x00167100`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Why am I loosing those particular bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcpy()` stops copying at the first null byte.  This means that you must use an address where at least the last three bytes are non-null.

Perhaps you can jump over the first instruction of the target function.

Comment: That was the problem however I have encountered a new problem. There is still the tail `\x00` byte and I have extra code after that byte. Any suggestions on getting around the `stycpy()` null byte problem.

Comment: @Blackninja543: The way to get around it is to ensure that your payload doesn't have any nulls other than as the last byte.